# Нужна помощь новичку в MVC и FXML

Tags: javafx, mvc, java

Пытался реализовать модель mvc с представлением в виде .fxml, сделанном в JavaFX Scene Builder, но возникла проблема с оповещением представления, после которого оно бы обновляло данные. Необходимо из модели вызвать срабатывание метода, который не только обновит состояние некоторых элементов представления, но и создаст новые или удалит существующие. Нашёл следующие вариант изменения параметров существующих элементов представления:

1. Повторное создание сцены:

   ```
   public class View extends Application {

   private static Stage stage;

   @Override
   public void start(Stage curStage) throws Exception{
       stage = curStage;
       stage.setScene(new Scene(FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FirstView.fxml")), stage.getWidth(), stage.getHeight()));
       stage.show();
   }

   public static void begin() {
       launch();
   }

   public void update() throws IOException {
       stage.setScene(new Scene(FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FirstView.fxml")), current.getScene().getWidth(), current.getScene().getHeight()));
   }
   ```

   И дальше изменять представление в методе `initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb)` контроллера.
2. `AnimationTimer` - актуально в основном для частой смены параметров элементов представления.
3. Биндинг. Нашёл в интрнете такой пример:

   ```
    label.textProperty().bind(textField.textProperty());
   ```

   Сделал по аналогии:

   ```
    label.textProperty().bind(Model.getIntance().getFirstUser().nickProperty());
   ```

   `nickProperty()` - аналогичным образом возвращает `StringProperty`.

   Но вот такой пример у меня уже почему-то не работал:

   ```
    textField.textProperty().bind(Model.getIntance().getFirstUser().nickProperty());
   ```

Так же встречал какую-то жуть на эту тему в интернете, где в файлах .fx в конструкторах визуального представления закладывались команды bind, связывая элементы представления с Java-переменными (в том числе и двухсторонним образом), но честно говоря из этого мало, что понял, т.к. у меня нету никаких .fx файлов, только .fxml, а даже если и создать .fx, то среда разработки будет считать, что это просто текстовой файл...

Помогите во всём этом разобраться. Все ли это способы обновить JavaFX-представление? Каким образом будет правильно обновлять представление? Как всё-таки сделать, чтобы ещё и добавлять/удалять объекты при обновлении представления?

Comment: @Andrey759, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Comment: По поводу
textField.textProperty().bind(Model.getIntance().getFirstUser().nickProperty());

Удалось выяснить, что хотябы двунаправленный биндинг работает в случае текстового поля =)